# Accessing Static value inside a REST API GET call

Tags: java, rest, static

I have developed a file based Client Server chat application, no database used.Now, I am creating some REST API for that chat server. 
when I am accessing a static List from server , I am getting the actual value. But when I am trying to access the list using @GET API call , it is returning null.

**Scenario is like this :**

```
 Package com.chat
 Class Server (){

    //Initializing Networking 
    //Establishing connectivity with Client.
        public static List<String> loggedInUserList;
        if (loggedInUserList == null) {
            loggedInUserList = new LinkedList<>();
        }
        String[] firstUserMessage = clientPacket.split("="); 

        if (firstUserMessage.length == 2) {
            String userName = firstUserMessage[1]; //2nd Part is always a UserName
            loggedInUserList.add(userName);
        }
}

Package com.chat
Class Client(){
    //Connecting with Server
     PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
     pwrite.println("username="+userName);
     pwrite.flush();
}

Package com.api
class Api(){

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    public String LoggedInUsers(){
        //Other logic
        Server.loggedInUserList; -----> Returning null 
    }
}
```

Both Client and Server are running while I am accessing the list from @GET.May be I am missing something very basic. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say there is code missing in _at least_ `class Api` to answer this question. Please add more code so one can see how `client` is generated and how `userList` is defined. Keep in mind to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @try-catch-finally Edited .Yeah, my question was ambiguous too.Hope,now it is clear.